# Как посмотреть(восстановить) видео?

Tags: windows, файлы, видео, восстановление, удаление

Я по ошибке удалил видео, восстановил удалённые видео(через recurva) и они не открываются(некоторые видео сохранили названия), пишет При воспроизведении файла проигрывателем Windows Media произошла ошибка.
Ошибка: 0xc00d36c4

Comment: Попробовать сменить проигрыватель. Или поискать специальную прогу, которая может забить пустоты чем-то осмысленным.

Comment: Попробуйте AVIDemux'ом открыть